# With Twitter Bootstrap 3 how can I have two scrollspys on a page?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

When I use Scrollspy it seems to show the scrollbar on the whole webpage. I looked at the source code and it seems to be hardcoded to the body element of the page, so I am guessing this means that it is impossible to put two scrollspys on a webpage?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried it? I am pretty sure this is supported, let me quote the [source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/3.0.0-wip/js/scrollspy.js):

```
$('[data-spy="scroll"]').each(function () {
  var $spy = $(this)
  $spy.scrollspy($spy.data())
})
```

Comment: Yes, I tried. You can add scroll spy to any elements but you only see one scrollbar. I looked on the web for a jsfiddle or something that shows the scrollbar on the element only but could not find anything

Comment: +1 point for trying. I guess bootstrap is designed to only have one scrollspy per page